# Load data into hosted feature service

Tags: data, arcgis-online

I have a feature service that is solely cloud-hosted. 
I need to load data into the service. 
I have many features to add, so I don't want to do this manually. 
Is there a way to load the features from the data directly to the feature service? 
I cannot do this after export, because then the data would be disconnected and multiple people are editing the service at once.
I cannot use Server, and I must leverage AGOL. 
Is there a re-existing tool? Something designed for AGOL?

Comment: UPDATE: It is much easier to do this now since AGOL was updated. This is no longer an issue

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. add hosted service to arcmap
2. create local copy for editing
3. start editing layer
4. navigate to temporary database in catalog
5. find associated layer and load data
6. save edits and stop editing
7. sync local edits to server

Tested and approved on a cloud-hosted feature service.